# True in one infinite model implies true in all other infinite models?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have some sentence in first order logic with equality, NOT using any non-logical symbols (functions, predicates and constants). If this sentence is true in some infinite model, is it then true in all infinite models?

I think that it is, but the only way I can think of proving it is by constructing a valuation in the second model using the valuation from the first and proving the claim by induction on the length of formulae, but this seems overly complicated, given the context. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand the restriction. Can we use function symbols? Then the assertion is very false, a counterexample is enough.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove this is to use the (upward and downward) Löwenheim-Skolem theorems. Suppose your sentence is true in a model of infinite cardinality $\kappa$, and suppose $\lambda$ is another infinite cardinal.  By Löwenheim-Skolem, your sentence is also true in *some* model of size $\lambda$.  But, thanks to the absence of any predicates, all models of size $\lambda$ are isomorphic.  So as soon as one of them satisfies your sentence they all do.

Alternative proofs can be given using quantifier-elimination or using Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games.